# Some docker swarm worker nodes cannot pull image

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

So here is a weird situation; I created a production environment using swarm with 1 manager and 3 worker nodes.

We are using our private repository to deploy our services on top this stack.

The problem is, when we try to deploy using the command below, it deploys in 2 workers but 1 worker and manager says; "**No such image**"

```
docker stack deploy -c leo4.yml leo4
```

However when we use this command below, then 3 worker nodes deploy without problem but this time manager says: "**No such image**"

```
docker stack deploy -c leo4.yml --with-registry-auth leo4
```

What I tried until now;

- Manual deployment of images works on all nodes including manager and workers
- Login to our private repository says: "**Login Succeeded**". So there is no connectivity problem.
- Manual editing of ~/.docker/config.json didn't help

What do you think the problem could be ?

Comment: Yes. To be sure about that I even created myself a public server with a valid SSL. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar swarm/registry issue and am working on it since it really impacts CI/CD. 4 nodes on OCI (3 managers, 1 worker). The registry is in the swarm and I can login/push/pull from the CLI to the private registry no trouble, from all nodes. But if don't manually pull the new images to each node then the stack will fail to start on that node due to "no image found". Anywhere the image has been pulled it will start no trouble.

I'm pretty sure it's down to trusting an SSL cert or setting the registry as "insecure", but traefik is handling my reverse proxy and certs and I'm at a loss for what I should do. Ref. https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/private-registry-swarm/

PortainerBE (also in the swarm) is able to login to registry but unable to browse the registry as well; with a non descript error of "invalid management configuration". Interestingly the VScode docker extension can browse the registry?

Answer (score 0):

As a prerequisite, the image must be in the registry, and not in the local docker engine.

You need to first run:

```shell
docker login ${registry}
```

And then, from the same terminal run:

```shell
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth ...
```

By doing that, the registry credentials are passed from the manager to the worker nodes. Credentials you cache directly on the workers will not apply because swarm is not running commands in the context of your user on that node. If you are running commands in CI, on ephemeral nodes, you need to be sure the node where you logged in was the same node where you ran the deploy.

If there are TLS issues, you can configure certificates either on the entire host, or in Docker per registry in /etc/docker/certs.d following [the various guides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26924766/596285).

Comment: Docker Swarm **can** deploy into 3 engines from ** private repository.** Meaning that we already completed those steps. The question was about after that.